# Selenium select_by_value using a variable

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a test case using Selenium where I select a value from a drop down using a variable (I need to use a variable because there are many items in the drop down and want to test them all) I am using the following code

```
select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name(entity_id)) --name of drop down
select.select_by_value(entity_type) -- option I want to select from drop down
```

I get the following error

'Invalid locator values passed in'  ,

So it looks like the variable is blank but when I send the variable to a text box elsewhere on the page it prints it correctly e.g.

```
inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_name("description")
inputElement.send_keys(entity_type)
```

If I hard code the value it works, am I trying to do something that's not possible?

Comment: Could you post the HTML of the drop down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the value you are trying to select seems to be numeric.
Please try

```
select.select_by_value(str(entity_type))
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that had me stumped for a while and now it works perfect.